# how to filter by year in fetchxml

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I have a DateTime parameter:

[image]

With FetchXML, I am trying to filter my data by just the Year part of my DateTime parameter:

```
 <filter type="and">
 <condition attribute="proposedstart" operator="in" value="@EventYear"/> 
 </filter>
```

`proposedstart` is **datetime** and `@EventYear` is **datetime**

I understand one way to do this is to say `on-or-before` **eventyear+1** and `on-or-after` **1/1/eventyear**

How can I solve this? **How do I filter on a condition where my the year of my datetime field in FetchXML is the same year as my datetime parameter?**

Answer (score 0):

You can format your datetime parameter in order to get only the year part.

Inside the expression put something like:

```
=Format(Parameters!EventYear.value,"yyyy")
```